# Cash tender type doesn't return serverTransactionId in square register API (Android)

Tags: square-connect

Whenever I initiate a transaction via square register API and the user uses cash as tender type, I don't get serverTransactionId with success response. I need the the serverTransactionId in order to call connect API's RetrieveTransaction endpoint. How can I call the RetrieveTransaction without getting back the serverTransactionId/transactionId from register API?

Comment: Can you share the response you are getting? Does it work with card payments?

Comment: It works with card payment. I do get serverTransactionId with card payment. But cash payment returns serverTransactionId as null.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`serverTransactionId` will be null for cash payments generally because the created transaction hasn't been assigned an ID by Square's servers before switching back to your application. Instead you'll want to list transactions, match find the right one by `clientTransactionId` and then you should be able to see the `serverTransactionId` if you want to make further operations on it. See https://docs.connect.squareup.com/api/register/android/com/squareup/sdk/register/ChargeRequest.Success.html#clientTransactionId for more details.

Comment: Thanks this helped me as well. By the way that is broken but I found this https://docs.connect.squareup.com/api/point-of-sale/android/com/squareup/sdk/pos/ChargeRequest.Success.html#clientTransactionId